# Disable Ctrl-H, Ctrl-P, and other Mac keyboard shortcuts

Tags: shortcut, keybindings

On GUIs with editable text focused on Mac I cannot seem to remap <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to shortcuts I want.

In IntelliJ I am trying to map my VIM ctrl shortcuts (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> next tab, <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> open file).  When I hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> I see that the "Navigate" tab highlights and the File... option is selected, but its function is overridden by moving up in the currently focused text edit window. The same problem is present with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> and trying to switch to the previous tab.

Any thoughts?

BTW, it's the same with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> and any other native text editing commands. They also do not exist in System Preferences > Keyboard anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

OS X uses Emacs-like keybindings in most text editing windows.  Normally you would change them to another text editing function but I don't know about functions like next tab or open a file.  Those would be mapped in the System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts window from a key to a menu in the IntelliJ app.

But, if it can accept the Emacs keybindings for other functions, try customizing it yourself.  Edit the `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` file (creating the KeyBindings folder and the dict file if they don't exist) with something like this.

`{
    "~d" = "deleteWordForward:";
    "^w" = "deleteWordBackward:";`

Save/exit then quit/restart the IntelliJ app (you don't need a reboot) and see if `Option-d` deletes the next word and `Control-w` deletes previous word.  If it works, research the Emacs bindings for next tab and open file.

Good luck!